# Halcon - initialize tuple of iconic variables

Tags: variables, initialization, tuples, halcon, iconic

How can I initialize a empty tuple of iconic variables?

I am trying to do this:

```
        concat_obj(AllStr, Str, AllStr)
```

AllStr is not initialized, so it throws an exception..

Comment: To initialise a iconic object, use gen_empty_obj(iconic_object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object needs to be initialsed first using `gen_empty_obj(str)` 
The code would look like this then,

```
gen_empty_obj(str) 
gen_empty_obj(AllStr)
str := iconic_object_1
AllStr := iconic_object_2
concat_obj(AllStr, str, AllStr)
```