# How to merge regions from region array in Halcon?

Tags: computer-vision, halcon

I am trying to iterate all rectangle regions in the image below and check which ones overlap with other regions. The overlapping regions need to be merged with eachother. I think my problem lies with iconic array initialisation and I had a look at a similar question over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62262328/halcon-initialize-tuple-of-iconic-variables) but that one is about iconic variables not region array.
This is what I tried:

```
* generated_rects is filled with 81 mostly overlapping rectangles
resultRegions := [] 
count_obj (generated_rects, nrOfRects)
for i := 0 to nrOfRects-1 by 1
    * get center
    region_features (generated_rects, 'row', r)
    region_features (generated_rects, 'column', c)     
    if (resultRegions == [])
        * copy region         
        continue
    endif
    * if there are result regions to check for overlap 
    count_obj (resultRegions, resultRegions_count) // error on: resultRegions
    for j := 0 to resultRegions_count -1 by 1
        select_obj (resultRegions, selectedRegion, j) // error on: resultRegions
        
        
        * get_region_index (resultRegions, r, c, Index) // error on: resultRegions
        * test_region_point (resultRegions, r, c, IsInside) // error on: resultRegions
    endfor    
endfor
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please upload generated_rects object?

Comment: @ Vladimir The generated rects is the image you see in my post.

Comment: I understand, but could you save the original region by using write_region and upload it?

Comment: [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sRbjnopINGIA2cOQHZomifLpb-UJrGsE/view?usp=sharing) is a link to my file

Comment: Do you need the information which of them are overlapping or just the resulting merge (20 regions)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without information which of them are overlapping:

```
union1 (generated_rects, RegionUnion)
connection (RegionUnion, ConnectedRegions)
```

[image]

Comment: I didnt thought of using connection after union1, so simple, you are my hero today, sir.